# Statistical test for survey data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, group-differences

I am a water quality scientist who is using water quality data from my region to determine if certain demographics are more likely to have poorer water quality (for example, by race).

The data was collected through a demographic survey to people who participated in water quality testing. Participants were categorized by race (in this example) and received a check mark if their water was above the drinking water quality guideline. I then summarized the amount of people in each demographic with poor water quality by percent (see below):

White or caucasian - 13.96%

American Indian - 0%

Asian American - 42%

Black or African American - 25%

Hispanic or Latinx - 50%

Other 33.33%

As I have not done statistical tests like this before, I am wondering which test I should use to determine if these percentages are statistically different from each other. Are percentages okay to use in this scenario, or would counts (103 out of 738 white/caucasian participants, for example) for each group be more useful for running statistical tests? I am most familiar with RStudio, and would be using that for my analysis.

Comment: Please explain how the percentages do not sum to 100%.  I would guess that's because you are double-counting people who identify in multiple classes -- but that means you won't be able to test most of the hypotheses that might interest you.  Note, too, that you *cannot* interpret any results as a relationship between demographics and water quality *in the population* because choosing to participate in testing is a confounding factor.

Comment: @whuber, this is because these percentages are relative to each group, not relative to the total number of participants. 

102 of 738 white participants (13.96%), 66 out of 132 Hispanic or Latino participants (50%), etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are other possibilities, but the most straightforward approach here would be to use a Chi Squared test. In R, this is the chisq.test() function.

You can put your data in a matrix with counts for water quality above the standard as the first row and counts for water quality below the standard as the second row. For example

```
mat <- matrix(c(120, 91, 40, 72, 64, 58), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
mat
```

and then

```
chisq.test(mat)
```